# Two variables with the same name

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I've miss-write my variables names using `i` for two variables, one is an `int` and the other `Uint16` like so :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    for(Uint16 ch = 5; ch < 20; ++ch) {
        Uint16 i = ch;
        //Some code
        cout << i;
    }
}
```

Using clang x86 5.1 it does compile, but which `i` will be displayed ? Is their a special rule ?

Comment: The rules on name lookup (C++11 3.4, especially 3.4.1) cover this. However, 3.3.10 (Name Hiding) is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an inner scope, a variable declaration will shadow any previous declaration. In your code sample the output will be the value of `ch` on each loop iteration.

If you were to output the value of `i` outside the inner for, the output would be the value of the `i` declared in the first for loop.

Comment: May you provide any source ?

Comment: Eh?  You posted some source.